# Align only the label of a caption right

Tags: captions, labels, line

I am using caption package and wanted to set the label of a caption (which is in a different line) to be aligned right, but the main text of the caption is aligned left, something like this:

[image]

How could it be done?

Comment: It depends on the document class and possibly the packages installed.  Please provide a Minimal Working Example, something we can copy and run, which illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the caption package you could define your own caption format, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{{\raggedleft #1\par}#3\par}
\captionsetup{format=myformat,singlelinecheck=off,textfont=bf}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Title of the table}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```